# Why is it that "$\tan\theta=(y/x) \nRightarrow \theta=\tan^{-1}(y/x)$"?

Tags: trigonometry

According to page 2 of [this document](https://www.math.utah.edu/lectures/math2210/9PostNotes.pdf), $\tan\theta=(y/x) \nRightarrow \theta=\tan^{-1}(y/x)$.

**Example question: Convert the point $(\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2},4)$ from Cartesian to Cylindrical coordinates.**

One part of solving this question initially boils down to finding all $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ such that $\tan\theta=\frac{y}{x}=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}=-1.$

The statement in the title confuses me because in examples I've seen so far (from different sources), the workings will go something like:

> $$\tan\theta=-1 \implies \theta = \tan^{-1}(-1)=-\pi/4 \in \left(-\pi/2,\pi/2\right).$$
>   Hence $\theta = -\pi/4 +k\pi$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}.$ We therefore have that $\theta$ is $3\pi/4$ or $7\pi/4$ for $\theta \in [0,2\pi].$

This in itself is actually now confusing me because I always thought $f^{-1}(y)=x \iff f(x)=y$, i.e. in this case that $\tan\theta =-1 \iff \theta= \tan^{-1}(-1)$.

But for $\theta=\tan^{-1}(-1)$, we know $\theta$ can only be $-\pi/4$ if it is to be in the range of $\tan^{-1}$, and with $\tan\theta=-1$ there are infinitely many solutions, so how can this be an if and only if relationship? Well according to the document hyperlinked above, it's not even a one-way relationship (contradicting the workings in the above box) and I'm rather confused.

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: In general, the iff is only true if $f(x)$ is one-to-one.

Comment: This is another case where the two-argument arctangent is warranted...

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician Also a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the iff is only true if $f(x)$ is one to one.  So the only error is that

$$f^{-1}(y)=x \iff f(x)=y\iff f(x)\text{ is one to one}$$

but $\tan(x)$ is not one to one.  To make it one to one, we usually apply domain/range restrictions.

Since the solutions to $\tan(\theta)=a$ are easily generalized, we often split it up over branches:

$$\tan^{-1}(a,k)=\tan^{-1}(a)+\pi k$$

Comment: Ah I now see why the iff doesn't hold here, thanks. What about the one-way implication though, i.e. why is that $\tan\theta=(y/x) \nRightarrow \theta=\tan^{-1}(y/x)$ when the workings suggest otherwise?

Comment: @Alex.F It is the case that it does imply, but not for all $\theta$.  You have to check the range of $\tan^{-1}$.

Comment: @Alex.F I'd recommend you check a graph.  Those always make it much clearer.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Many thanks, but can I just ask why in the last line of your answer you have $k\pi/2$ rather than $k\pi$ since I thought we're using $\tan(x)=\tan(k\pi+x)$?

Comment: (Sorry just to note I reposted the comment above after deleting the initial one because the formatting was awful and it wouldn't let me edit it)

Comment: @Alex.F No problem lol, I totally understand with comments.

Comment: Wolframalpha (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solutions+to+tanx%3D-1) says solutions to $\tanx=-1$ are given by $x=-\pi/4+n\pi$ and the $-\pi/4$ is from the inverse. So I still don't understand the $\pi/2$ bit. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Alex.F Weird, it is not fully correct.  View [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fchlqndttf)

Comment: That shows that all elements of the solution set $\{\dots,-\frac{5\pi}{4},-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4},\dots\}$ only differ by multiples of $k\pi$?

Comment: @Alex.F Huh, well I do make mistakes.  :D

Comment: Haha no worries. Thanks again! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Alex.F No problem, happy holidays!

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use the mathematical notation `arctan`, not the hand-held computer notation $\tan^{-1}$.

Second, as $\tan$ is *not* a bijection, since it is a periodic function, what is defined is the inverse function of its *restriction* to a domain on which its restriction is bijective. The chosen interval is $\;\Bigl]-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi 2\Bigr[$. Thus the full definition of $\arctan$ is
$$\theta=\arctan\frac yx\iff \tan\theta=\frac yx\enspace\textbf{and}\enspace\boxed{\theta\in\Bigl]-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi 2\Bigr[.} $$

Comment: Tho I personally prefer the notation $\arctan$, the notation of putting $-1$ as a superscript for inverse functions is certainly not just confined to handhelds.

Comment: @J. M. isn't a mathematician: The first time I saw this notation was on the key of a Casio (quite long ago). Mathematically, it's  nonsense since tan has no inverse. I suspect it's used only by pure mimicry and mental laziness.

Comment: "tan has no inverse" - well, you thus have to choose one out of infinitely many branches, much like having to choose what $\sqrt{z}$ is out of two possibilities, or what $\log z$ ought to be out of many possible values.

Comment: *Per se*, it has no inverse.